# Location Updating on basis of device state

Tags: java, android, google-api, location, activity-recognition

I need to get location(By fusedlocation API) of user after ActivityRecognition Detect user state (Which calls every 3 mins), like IN_VEHICLE,ON_FOOT,RUNNING etc.

On each event i need user location after regular interval For example:

if user is still then `setInterval(5*60*60*1000);` and check for next location 
update in not before 5 hour. But ActivityRecognation Will call every 3 min.

if user is Running then `setInterval(2*60*1000);` and check for next location update in not before/After 2 mins. But ActivityRecognation Will call every 3 min.

if user is running then send location every 1 mins
if user is Driving then send location every 15 mins.

I tried to set boolean false in `onConnected` to false and true at class level. But it always turn into true because whole Intent service is called after 3 mins.

```
if (startLocationFirst){
requestLocatonSetting(5*60*60*1000,3*60*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); 
  LocationAPIclient.connect();// RequestLocation and GoogleAPIClient won't call until device comes from another ActivityRecognation State running,walking etc. And keep Updating location every 5 hours.
              }
```

Issue I am current having

- ActivityRecognation Gets User State every 3 mins but it should not enter into `startLocationFirst` boolean until it comes from another ActivityRecognation State and keep updating location as set inside `startLocationFirst`

Here is IntentService With FusedLocation

```
public class Activity_Recognized_Service extends IntentService implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, LocationListener {
    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public static final String TAG = "###RECOGNISED SRVCE###";
    Timer timer;
    GoogleApiClient LocationAPIclient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    boolean startLocationFirst=true;


    public Activity_Recognized_Service() {
        super("Activity_Recognized_Service");
    }

    public Activity_Recognized_Service(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "On Handle Intent");
        if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ActivityRecognition Has Result");
            ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
            handleDetectedActivities(result.getProbableActivities());
            Navigation_Drawer nav = new Navigation_Drawer();
            nav.UserMovementResult(result);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG,"On Create Calling");
        if (LocationAPIclient == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Location API is NULL Value Of This ");
            LocationAPIclient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }

    }

    private void handleDetectedActivities(List<DetectedActivity> probableActivities) {

        for (DetectedActivity activity : probableActivities) {
            switch (activity.getType()) {
                case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE:
                    Log.d(TAG, "In Vehicle " + activity.getConfidence());
                    if (activity.getConfidence() >= 75) {
                        //Send Notification To User
                        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                        builder.setContentText("In Vehicle");
                        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
                        builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
                        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());
                        requestLocatonSetting(10*60*1000,8*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //5 hours= hours * 60 min*60 sec* 1000 milliseconds
                        //requestLocatonSetting(6*60*1000,6*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //TEST
                        LocationAPIclient.connect();
                        if (startLocationFirst){
                            Log.d(TAG,"Start Location Update For Car");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE:
                    Log.d(TAG, "On Bicycle " + activity.getConfidence());
                    if (activity.getConfidence() >= 75) {
                        //Send Notification To User
                        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                        builder.setContentText("On Bicycle");
                        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
                        builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
                        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());
                        requestLocatonSetting(7*60*1000,5*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //5 hours= hours * 60 min*60 sec* 1000 milliseconds
                        //requestLocatonSetting(6*60*1000,6*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //TEST
                        LocationAPIclient.connect();
                    }
                    break;
                case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT:
                    Log.d(TAG, "On Foot " + activity.getConfidence());
                    if (activity.getConfidence() >= 75) {
                        //Send Notification To User
                        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                        builder.setContentText("On Foot");
                        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
                        builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
                        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());
                    }
                    break;
                case DetectedActivity.RUNNING:
                    Log.d(TAG, "On Running " + activity.getConfidence());
                    if (activity.getConfidence() >= 75) {
                        //Send Notification To User
                        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                        builder.setContentText("Running");
                        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
                        builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
                        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());
                        requestLocatonSetting(3*60*1000,2*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //5 hours= hours * 60 min*60 sec* 1000 milliseconds
                        //requestLocatonSetting(6*60*1000,6*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //TEST
                        LocationAPIclient.connect();
                    }
                    break;
                case DetectedActivity.STILL:
                    Log.d(TAG, "On Still " + activity.getConfidence());
                    if (activity.getConfidence() >= 75) {
                        //Send Notification To User
                        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                        builder.setContentText("Still");
                        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
                        builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
                        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());

                            requestLocatonSetting(5*60*60*1000,3*60*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //5 hours= hours * 60 min*60 sec* 1000 milliseconds
                          //  requestLocatonSetting(3*60*1000,2*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //TEST
                            LocationAPIclient.connect();


                    }
                    break;
                case DetectedActivity.TILTING:
                    Log.d(TAG, "On Tilting " + activity.getConfidence());
                    if (activity.getConfidence() >= 75) {
                        //Send Notification To User
                        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                        builder.setContentText("Tilting");
                        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
                        builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
                        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());

                        requestLocatonSetting(3*60*1000,2*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //5 hours= hours * 60 min*60 sec* 1000 milliseconds
                        //requestLocatonSetting(6*60*1000,6*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //TEST
                        LocationAPIclient.connect();
                    }
                    break;
                case DetectedActivity.WALKING:
                    Log.d(TAG, "On Walking " + activity.getConfidence());
                    if (activity.getConfidence() >= 75) {
                        //Send Notification To User
                        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                        builder.setContentText("Let's Walk");
                        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
                        builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
                        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());
                        requestLocatonSetting(3*60*1000,2*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //5 hours= hours * 60 min*60 sec* 1000 milliseconds
                        LocationAPIclient.connect();

                    }
                    break;
                case DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN:
                    Log.d(TAG, "UnKnown " + activity.getConfidence());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setTimer(int Minutes) {
        Log.d(TAG, "==================================================");
        Log.d(TAG, "Set Timeer Starts It will Run Every " + Minutes);
        int MilliSeconds = 60000 * Minutes;
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            //CODE THAT YOU WANT TO EXECUTE AT GIVEN INTERVAL


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, MilliSeconds);
        Log.d(TAG, "==================================================");
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "On Connected Running");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
         mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(LocationAPIclient);
        if (mCurrentLocation!=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Last Known Location Is not Null ");
            new Location_sendeToServer_AsyncTask(this).execute(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()),String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()),String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy()));
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG,"Last Known Location Is NULL Start Location Updates");
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(LocationAPIclient,mLocationRequest,this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG,"On Location Changed Calling");
        mCurrentLocation=location;
        new Location_sendeToServer_AsyncTask(this).execute(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()),String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()),String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy()));
        Log.d(TAG,"Stopping Location Update");
       // LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(LocationAPIclient,this);
    }

    public void requestLocatonSetting(int Interval,int FastestInterval,int LocationAccuracy){
        mLocationRequest=new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(Interval);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FastestInterval);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationAccuracy);

    }

}
```

Comment: This question is not for official sources. any one can answer

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Here is a better example using only the code you have provided above:

Use this service when registering your ActivityRecognitionApi:

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public static final String TAG = "###RECOGNISED SRVCE###";

    private GoogleApiClient apiClient;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private DetectedActivity lastActivity;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        apiClient.connect();
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, new Intent(this, YourIntentService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ActivityRecognition Has Result");
            ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
            handleDetectedActivity(result);

            /* You should really use LocalBroadcastManager to send events out to an activity for UI updates */

//            Navigation_Drawer nav = new Navigation_Drawer();
//            nav.UserMovementResult(result);
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "On Connected Running");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(apiClient);
        if (location!=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Last Known Location Is not Null ");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourIntentService.class).putExtra("lastKnown", location);
            startService(intent);

            /* No more need for this! */
//            new Location_sendeToServer_AsyncTask(this).execute(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()),String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()),String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy()));
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG,"Last Known Location Is NULL Start Location Updates");
            updateLocationSetting(5*60*60*1000,3*60*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
//            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(apiClient,mLocationRequest,this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    private void handleDetectedActivity(ActivityRecognitionResult result) {
        DetectedActivity mostProbableActivity = result.getMostProbableActivity();
        switch (result.getMostProbableActivity().getType()) {
            case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE:
//                    Log.d(TAG, "In Vehicle " + activity.getConfidence());
                if (mostProbableActivity.getConfidence() >= 75 && mostProbableActivity != lastActivity) {
                    //Send Notification To User
//                        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
//                        builder.setContentText("In Vehicle");
//                        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
//                        builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
//                        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());
                    //requestLocatonSetting(6*60*1000,6*60*1000,LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //TEST
                    if (apiClient.isConnected()) {
                        updateLocationSetting(10 * 60 * 1000, 8 * 60 * 1000, LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //5 hours= hours * 60 min*60 sec* 1000 milliseconds
                        lastActivity = mostProbableActivity;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE:
                Log.d(TAG, "On Bicycle " + mostProbableActivity.getConfidence());
                if (mostProbableActivity.getConfidence() >= 75 && mostProbableActivity != lastActivity) {
                    //Send Notification To User
//                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
//                    builder.setContentText("On Bicycle");
//                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
//                    builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
//                    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());
                    if (apiClient.isConnected()) {
                        updateLocationSetting(7 * 60 * 1000, 5 * 60 * 1000, LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //5 hours= hours * 60 min*60 sec* 1000 milliseconds
                        lastActivity = mostProbableActivity;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT:
                Log.d(TAG, "On Foot " + mostProbableActivity.getConfidence());
                if (mostProbableActivity.getConfidence() >= 75) {
                    DetectedActivity nextHighest = result.getProbableActivities().get(1);
                    if (nextHighest.getType() == DetectedActivity.RUNNING && nextHighest != lastActivity) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "On Running " + mostProbableActivity.getConfidence());
                        //Send Notification To User
//                        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
//                        builder.setContentText("Running");
//                        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
//                        builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
//                        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());
                        if (apiClient.isConnected()) {
                            updateLocationSetting(3 * 60 * 1000, 2 * 60 * 1000, LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //5 hours= hours * 60 min*60 sec* 1000 milliseconds
                            lastActivity = nextHighest;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (nextHighest.getConfidence() >= 75 && nextHighest != lastActivity) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "On Walking " + mostProbableActivity.getConfidence());
                        //Send Notification To User
//                        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
//                        builder.setContentText("Let's Walk");
//                        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
//                        builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
//                        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());

                        if (apiClient.isConnected()) {
                            updateLocationSetting(3 * 60 * 1000, 2 * 60 * 1000, LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //5 hours= hours * 60 min*60 sec* 1000 milliseconds
                            lastActivity = nextHighest;
                        }
                    }
                    //Send Notification To User
//                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
//                    builder.setContentText("On Foot");
//                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
//                    builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
//                    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());
                }
                break;
            case DetectedActivity.STILL:
                Log.d(TAG, "On Still " + mostProbableActivity.getConfidence());
                if (mostProbableActivity.getConfidence() >= 75 && mostProbableActivity != lastActivity) {
                    //Send Notification To User
//                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
//                    builder.setContentText("Still");
//                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
//                    builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
//                    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());

                    if (apiClient.isConnected()) {
                        updateLocationSetting(5 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000, LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //5 hours= hours * 60 min*60 sec* 1000 milliseconds
                        lastActivity = mostProbableActivity;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case DetectedActivity.TILTING:
                Log.d(TAG, "On Tilting " + mostProbableActivity.getConfidence());
                if (mostProbableActivity.getConfidence() >= 75 && mostProbableActivity != lastActivity) {
                    //Send Notification To User
//                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
//                    builder.setContentText("Tilting");
//                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
//                    builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
//                    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());

                    if (apiClient.isConnected()) {
                        updateLocationSetting(3 * 60 * 1000, 2 * 60 * 1000, LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //5 hours= hours * 60 min*60 sec* 1000 milliseconds
                        lastActivity = mostProbableActivity;
                    }
                }
                break;
//            case DetectedActivity.WALKING:
//                Log.d(TAG, "On Walking " + mostProbableActivity.getConfidence());
//                if (mostProbableActivity.getConfidence() >= 75) {
//                    //Send Notification To User
//                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
//                    builder.setContentText("Let's Walk");
//                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.elaxer_x);
//                    builder.setContentTitle("Elaxer");
//                    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());
//
//                    if (apiClient.isConnected()) {
//                        updateLocationSetting(3 * 60 * 1000, 2 * 60 * 1000, LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //5 hours= hours * 60 min*60 sec* 1000 milliseconds
//                    }
//                }
//                break;
            case DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN:
                Log.d(TAG, "UnKnown " + mostProbableActivity.getConfidence());
                lastActivity = mostProbableActivity;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void updateLocationSetting(int Interval, int FastestInterval, int LocationAccuracy) {
        LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
        request.setInterval(Interval);
        request.setFastestInterval(FastestInterval);
        request.setPriority(LocationAccuracy);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            //TODO DO SOMETHING HERE!
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(apiClient, request, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

And this would be the IntentService to use instead of using the AsyncTask you were using:

```
public class YourIntentService extends IntentService {

    public YourIntentService() {
        super("YOUR_INTENT_SERVICE");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            if (LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {
                LocationResult result = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
                Location location = result.getLastLocation();
                Log.d("YourIntentService", "Got new location: " + location);
            }
            else if (intent.hasExtra("lastKnown")) {
                Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra("lastKnown");
                Log.d("YourIntentService", "Got last known location: " + location);
            }
            else if (LocationAvailability.hasLocationAvailability(intent)) {
                LocationAvailability locationAvailability = LocationAvailability.extractLocationAvailability(intent);
                Log.d("YourIntentService", "Location Availability: " + locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This intent service can handle blocking network requests as long as they are called within the `onHandleIntent`.

I modified the `handleDetectedActivity` code a bit so that on every activity update, a new location update doesn't occur.

---

First off, I would not suggest you use an [`IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) the way you are now, as the service will be killed once it exits `onHandleIntent`, which would cause a lot of issues since you are relying on callbacks. All of this should be put into a [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) instead.

As for handling location updates based on activity recognition, I did find this nice library that simplifies this and is pretty easy to use. https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib

Here is an example of how to use the library with location updates based on activity results.

```
SmartLocation.with(this).location(new LocationBasedOnActivityProvider(new LocationBasedOnActivityProvider.LocationBasedOnActivityListener() {
    @Override
    public LocationParams locationParamsForActivity(DetectedActivity detectedActivity) {
        if (detectedActivity.getConfidence() >= 75) {
            LocationParams.Builder builder = new LocationParams.Builder();
            switch (detectedActivity.getType()) {
                case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE:
                    builder.setInterval(/*Interval*/)
                            .setAccuracy(/*Locaiton Accuracy*/);
                    break;

                case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE:
                    /* So on and so forth.... */

                    break;
            }
            return builder.build();
        }
        return null;
    }
})).start(new OnLocationUpdatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationUpdated(Location location) {
        //Do what you need here.
    }
});
```

This should be dropped into a `Service` in the `onStart` function, with `onStartCommand` handling changes based on the intent extras you provide. You can also use this library to get the last known location, and to get a single fix.

One last thing, I would recommend you get away from the `AsyncTask` if you are passing contexts to it. Instead use the `IntentService`, since the `onHandleIntent` function is run in a background thread, and you can use the `IntentService`'s context to perform whatever tasks you need with it. You can pass the `Location` object as an extra in the intent when you start your `IntentService`.

Comment: U might be right. But i already checked this lib on github and we don't want to use any additional lib.This would be fix by some logic without any additional library

Comment: Your code logic says checking if last activity is not equal to current. If activity changes  then enter into scope.I am right? please clear me if i am wrong

Comment: As in code you use lastActivity (DetectedActivity) if its same as last. So it will be null cuz its not initialized and putting value after it

Comment: You won't get result of ActivityRecognition cuz as per your code you are not setting API with play service. It would be better if you explain your code bit more

Comment: I'm assuming you are going to use the LocationUpdateService as the intent for you activity recognition api, as that is how it appears in your original code. Wherever you call for activity recognition, instead of your IntentService, use this new service. As for the logic, everytime you call to update location on activity change, it ignores your timing, and attempts to get a new location. To avoid this, I only update location when the previous activity is different from the current.

Answer (score 1):

I execute this code after adding few lines to same code as above.

- First I declare static int at class level in `IntentService` because `DectectedActivity.getType()` return int. `static int detectedActivity;`
- Then at i check whether its same state as last like this `if (activity.getConfidence() >= 75 && activity.getType()!=detectedActivity)`

That's it.Thanks to @Pablo Baxter who gave me some kind of logic to apply.I tested this on `IntentService` but i need to test it on service so i can update locations.Will update soon.